# Nginx module redirect

Tags: redirect, module, nginx

Good day

I am writing a module for Nginx, that should redirect user to certain (local) URLs, if several conditions apply - something like ngx_http_rewrite_module (Though I couldn't find redirection code in that module).

My code successfully runs on required events, but I am unable to redirect user to another page.

I've tried `ngx_http_internal_redirect`, but it didn't work:

```
static ngx_str_t  ngx_redirect_script = ngx_string("/dst.php");
return ngx_http_internal_redirect(r, &ngx_redirect_script , &r->args);
```

Perhaps somebody knows how to do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, this worked:

```
ngx_http_internal_redirect(r, &ngx_redirect_script , &r->args);
return NGX_HTTP_OK;
```

Comment: But did this actually redirect you to that other page? In my module, it's just getting the output of that other page and rendering it with the same URL.  I want /test to point to -> /redirect, but it's just rendering /redirect's content on /test.

Comment: I would very much like to answer you, but it was so long ago that I don't even remember writing this question, let alone how that module behaved :(

Comment: @RaisinBranCrunch If you want to generate an HTTP redirect, you can check how it is [handled](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/41a241b3ef74dbbe3d82ab2ebbe682919e4a0b90/src/http/modules/ngx_http_static_module.c#L148) in the `ngx_http_static_module`.